# mockito test error Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have been getting writing unit tests for a method that invokes `jdbcTemplate.query` and returns some data. It doesn't seems to be working and throwing exception.

Here's the code.

```
@Test
    public void NewDealDaoGetClientOwnershipValuesTest() {
        List<OptionView> optionViews = new ArrayList<OptionView>();
        optionViews.add(new OptionView("one", "two"));

        when(jdbcTemplate.query("<some sql query>", newDealDaoImpl.getResultSetExtractor(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))).thenReturn(optionViews);
        assertEquals(newDealDaoImpl.getClientOwnershipValues(), optionViews);
    }
```

Error message

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 3 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Just for your information that method `newDealDaoImpl.getResultSetExtractor` takes 3 arguments<String, String, String>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using argument matchers:

```
Mockito.anyString()
```

on an object that is not managed by Mockito (mock, spy etc.)

Try to pass an empty String or other random value to your:

```
newDealDaoImpl.getResultSetExtractor(...)
```

Comment: fixed code - `Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(Mockito.anyString(), (ResultSetExtractor<Object>) Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(optionViews);`

Comment: Try to use any(ResultSetExtractor.class). anyObject() should be the last resort. Cheers